# How do I cycle through these elements using selenium in python and get the XPATH value in return?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to be able to cycle through this table's tabs and return the XPATHs and tab names.

I am using the python selenium webdriver.

This is the main container containing all the tabs from which i want the data

When i enter the website into selenium webdriver, i want it to first find this chart_table_container.

```
<div id="chart_table_container" class="tab_container ui-tabs ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content">

<ul class="tabs ui-tabs-nav ui-corner-all ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header" role="tablist">
```

Then I want it to cycle through the 3 tabs below, sometimes there might be more than 3. and the XPATH might be different, so I want to automate that.

Is there a way to cycle through the tabs below and return the XPATHs (//*[@id="ui-id-3"]) and also the name of the tabs (First Order) into a dictionary?

**This is an example of one tabs**

```
<li role="tab" tabindex="0" class="ui-tabs-tab ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-tab ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" aria-controls="chart_wrapper_datatable_first_order" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true">

<a href="#chart_wrapper_datatable_first_order" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" id="ui-id-3">First Order</a></li>
```

**This is another tab**

```
<li role="tab" tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-tab ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-tab" aria-controls="chart_wrapper_datatable_second_order" aria-labelledby="ui-id-4" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false">

<a href="#chart_wrapper_datatable_second_order" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" id="ui-id-4">Second Order</a></li>
```

**This is anothertab**

```
<li role="tab" tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-tab ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-tab" aria-controls="chart_wrapper_datatable_third_order" aria-labelledby="ui-id-5" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false">

<a href="#chart_wrapper_datatable_third_order" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" id="ui-id-5">Third Order</a></li>
```

Does selenium have the capacity to do this? I looked through the documentation but I only found ways to search for the actual tabs using the XPATHs not find all the XPATHs at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try this:

```
tabs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//li[@role= "tab"]/a') 

tabs = [[a.get_attribute("innerHTML"), "//*[@id=" + "".join(a.get_attribute("id")) + "]"] for a in tabs ]
```

If li classes is always the same, change xpath to [@class= "li class"] or [@role= "tab" and @class= "li class"]

Comment: is there a way to add a wait to this because sometimes some of the elements dont get recorded, i think the page gets skipped before it fully loads

Comment: is this correct?

tabs = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'.//li[@role= "tab"]/a')))
        
tabs = [[a.get_attribute("innerHTML"), "//*[@id=" + "".join(a.get_attribute("id")) + "]"] for a in tabs ]

Comment: @anarchy, yeap, is looks like correct code. It will work fine. Or you can change wait condition to presence_of_all_elements_located

Answer (score 0):

To print the *table names* such as **First Order**, **Second Order**, **Third Order**, etc you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#chart_table_container>ul.ui-tabs-nav li>a.ui-tabs-anchor[id^='ui-id-']")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='chart_table_container']/ul[contains(@class, 'ui-tabs-nav')]//li/a[@class='ui-tabs-anchor' and starts-with(@id, 'ui-id-')]")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: is there a way to get the xpath as well using this method?

Comment: @anarchy _xpath_ is something you need to construct to locate an element.